# How to loop the map and use the value to create a path in groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have a map like this

```
   def map = [
          var1 : "var1",
          var2 : "var2",
          var3 : "var3"
    ]
```

and have a method to use the value to create some paths

```
 class test{
    Method start(){
      Method.newInstance()
                .withName("test1/A1/(should be the value in the map)")
        } 
    }

test.newInstance().start()
```

So how can I loop the map and put these three values as parameters to .withName() to create three different paths?

Comment: Your code includes `(should be the value in the map)` but you show a `Map` with multiple values. It isn't clear what your requirements are here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be with something like this:

```
class Test{
    def map = [
        var1 : "var1",
        var2 : "var2",
        var3 : "var3"
    ]

    List<Method> start(){
        map.values().collect { val ->
            Method.newInstance()
                .withName("test1/A1/${val}")
        }
    } 
}

new Test().start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem now is can't return List<Method>, any other approach?

Comment: What do you want to return?

Comment: change "collect" to "inject". Look the type of map.values().collect { val ->
            Method.newInstance()
                .withName("test1/A1/${val}")
        }

Comment: What does `"Look the type of map.values().collect { val -> Method.newInstance() .withName("test1/A1/${val}") }"` mean?